# JavaScript interop calls error when using AuthorizeRouteView in Blazor Server App App.razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor-server-side

I am implementing AuthorizeRouteView in App.razor file of Blazor Server App but I always get an error when the application runs

> InvalidOperationException: JavaScript interop calls cannot be issued at this time. This is because the component is being statically rendered. When prerendering is enabled, JavaScript interop calls can only be performed during the OnAfterRenderAsync lifecycle method.

Below is the App.razor content

```
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly" PreferExactMatches="@true">
<Found Context="routeData">
    <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
        <NotAuthorized>
            <Login />
        </NotAuthorized>
    </AuthorizeRouteView>
    <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />

</Found>
<NotFound>
    <CascadingAuthenticationState>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
        </LayoutView>
    </CascadingAuthenticationState>
</NotFound>
```

Even if I comment out the Login component the error still shows.
What am I missing

Comment: Just like the error is telling you. Somewhere in the code the Interop is used in a OnInitialized function. The Interopt can only be used after the full page is loaded just like the error tells you (OnAfterRenderAsync)

Comment: Am actually stuck because there is no where in the code I see this happening

Comment: The error tells that blazor call the JavaScript interop in the incorrect lifestyle. Where do you call it, can show it?

Comment: Your `App.razor` is almost certainly not the cause of your error.